# Magento 2.3 Class does not exist on error Compilation

Tags: magento2.3.2, setup-di-compile

When I tried to do the compilation via `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, I got the following error.

[image]

I installed [Landofcoder's SMS notification extension](https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-sms-notification-extension.html). I was thinking the issue is arising due to this one.

Comment: Helper data doesn't exist and give permission to generated folder

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, at present, generated folder has 775 permissions

Comment: Does this TEXT\Smsnotifications\Helper\Data.php exist or not and make if 777 for generated folder

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, i am unable to check for that TEXT\Smsnotifications\Helper\Data.php, where that is exist.

And, i just given 777 for generated folder

Comment: check in app/code/ TEXT/Smsnotifications/Helper/Data.php (or) Vendor/text/TEXT/Smsnotifications/Helper/Data.php

Comment: @aravind, my extension path is app/code/Lof/SmsNotification/

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, No. same error is coming as per my description

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara do you have helper in that ? check namespace and class given correctly..

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara in case did you call that helper file from somewhere ? Check helper data is correctly called..

Comment: do with generated permission - chmod -R 777 generated